# Github Login with Graphcool

Tags: github, graphql, apollo, graphcool

I am attempting to implement a GitHub Login with GraphCool. So far:

#### Steps

1. I've run: `graphcool add-template auth/github`
2. I uncommented the links in the `graphcool.yml` and `typs.graphql` files
3. I setup a GitHub OAuth app
4. I added my client name and secret to local environment variables.
5. I ran `graphcool deploy`

#### Results

Under functions it says I have `loggedInUser` and `githubAuthentication`. I also seem to have a githubUserId added to `createUser`

#### Problem

From here I am stuck. I'm not sure what to do. I am not sure where to obtain a github code. I've implemented OAuth with Github before directly via their API and with Firebase. I have the following questions:

1. In Github, what should I set the **Authorization callback URL**? Doesn't that need to point to graphcool?
2. How does the OAuth pop-up window get launched so I can approve my app?
3. How do I obtain Github user data like `displayName` and `photoUrl`. Can I add that data to a new user when `createUser` is ran?

I have modified the username password template to createUsers with additional fields in the past. I know I have to modify the types and .ts files in the template. It seems like I may be able to obtain specific user details around **line 29** in the **githubAuthentication.ts** file:

```
const graphcool = fromEvent(event)
const api = graphcool.api('simple/v1')
const { githubCode } = event.data
const githubToken: string = await getGithubToken(githubCode)
const githubUser = await getGithubUser(githubToken)
const user: User = await getGraphcoolUser(api, githubUser.id)
  .then(r => r.User)
let userId: string | null = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure where to obtain a github code.

**Short Answer:** in whichever way you would normally obtain a Github code.

**Long Answer:**

You can follow this guide to see how to authorize against a Github OAuth app: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/

Or, follow the instructions from the template `README.md`:

> **Obtaining a test code**
>
> First, update the configuration of the OAuth app on Github you just
>   created:
>
> - Set the Homepage URL to http://localhost:8000/
> - Set the Application Callback URL to http://localhost:8000/login.html
> - Replace **CLIENT_ID** in login.html with the client id of your OAuth app
> - Server login.html, for example by using python -m SimpleHTTPServer
> - Open https://localhost:8000/login.html in a browser, open the DevTools and authenticate with your Github account
> - Copy the code printed in the Console of your DevTools

This being `index.html`:

```
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    // Github client id
    const client_id = '__CLIENT_ID__'
    // Will extract code from current url
    const githubCode = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')[0].split('code=')[1]
    if (githubCode) {
      // call Graphcool authenticateGithubUser mutation
      console.log(githubCode)
    }
    function getgithubCode() {
      window.location = `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&scope=user`
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="getgithubCode();">Authenticate with Github</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, long story short... With GraphCool, I have to handle OAuth on my own and I pass the code to graphcool? Is the code enough to schema stitch github, or do I also need a github token?

Answer (score 0):

github's  doc  is confusing.  if you use  http-server  to start a  server, the port  must be  localhost:8080,so you can change  port  8000->8080

this  server use for get  githubCode.  In the code ,if   your app's Client ID is valid, you can find githubCode In the console.  I can get the githubCode, but after that , mutation has error.

Comment: Notice  ,doc's port  is  8000  not 8080.  Get githubCode,only need  configure   github's  client-id.  you don't need to graph cool deploy.